# How golang's "defer" capture closure's parameter?

Tags: go, closures

Here is my code ([run](http://play.golang.org/p/IBm_7sGGHt)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var whatever [5]struct{}

    for i := range whatever {
        fmt.Println(i)
    } // part 1

    for i := range whatever {
        defer func() { fmt.Println(i) }()
    } // part 2

    for i := range whatever {
        defer func(n int) { fmt.Println(n) }(i)
    } // part 3
}
```

Output:

`0
1
2
3
4
4
3
2
1
0
4
4
4
4
4`

Question: What's the difference between part 2 & part 3? Why part 2 output "44444" instead of "43210"?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The 'part 2' closure captures the variable 'i'. When the code in the closure (later) executes, the variable 'i' has the value which it had in the last iteration of the range statement, ie. '4'. Hence the

```
4 4 4 4 4
```

part of the output.

The 'part 3' doesn't capture any outer variables in its closure. As the [specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) say:

> Each time the "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked.

So each of the defered function calls has a different value of the 'n' parameter. It is the value of the 'i' variable in the moment the defer statement was executed. Hence the

```
4 3 2 1 0
```

part of the output because:

> ... deferred calls are executed in LIFO order immediately before the surrounding function returns ...

---

The key point to note is that the 'f()' in 'defer f()' is not *executed* when the defer statement executes

**but**

the expression 'e' in 'defer f(e)' *is evaluated* when the defer statement executes.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address another example in order to improve the understanding of `defer mechanish`, run this snippet as it is first, then switch order of the statements marked as (A) and (B), and see the result to yourself.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Component struct {
    val int
}

func (c Component) method() {
    fmt.Println(c.val)
}

func main() {
    c := Component{}
    defer c.method()  // statement (A)
    c.val = 2 // statement (B)
}
```

I keep wonderng what are the correct keywords or concepts to apply here. It looks like that the expression `c.method` is evaluated, thus returning a function binded to the actual state of the component "c" (like taking an snapshot of the component's internal state). 
I guess the answer involves not only `defer mechanish` also how `funtions with value or pointer receiver` works. Do note that it also happens that if you change the func named `method` to be a `pointer receiver` the defer prints c.val as 2, not as 0.

Comment: maybe this is a complex example of something like this https://play.golang.org/p/yNma_82QIJ9