# Defer called in go routine

Tags: go

I believe I understand defer well in the normal use cases. Such as the one listed in this question [Golang defer behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720097/golang-defer-behavior). However I am a little perplexed as to what is happening when defer is called inside a goroutine that does not return. Here is the code in question.

```
func start_consumer() {
    conn, _ := amqp.Dial("amqp://username:password@server.com")
    //defer conn.Close()

    ch, _ := conn.Channel()
    //defer ch.Close()

    q, _ := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "test", // name
        true,   // durable
        false,  // delete when unused
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // arguments
    )

    _ = ch.Qos(
        3,     // prefetch count
        0,     // prefetch size
        false, // global
    )

    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for {
            msgs, _ := ch.Consume(
                q.Name, // queue
                "",     // consumer
                false,  // ack
                false,  // exclusive
                false,  // no-local
                false,  // no-wait
                nil,    // args
            )

            for d := range msgs {
                log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
                d.Ack(true)
            }

            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    <-forever
}
```

This function is called from

```
go start_consumer()
```

This is likely a misunderstanding by me how channels work but I though forever would not return since it's waiting for a value to be passed to it.

Comment: what are you asking exactly? what behavior are you expecting and what is happening?

Comment: it's simple, the deferred statement executes when the function returns. If the function doesn't return, the deferred statement doesn't execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Go Blog's [Defer, Panic, and Recover](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover) post referenced in the previous question does a great job explaining how defer statements work.

> A defer statement pushes a function call onto a list. The list of saved calls is executed after the surrounding function returns. Defer is commonly used to simplify functions that perform various clean-up actions.

In your case since the goroutine does not return, the list of deferred calls will never be run.  This makes the defer statement unnecessary in this context.

Comment: I wonder if `defer` statements would make sense related to `SIGTERM` signals? For instance: you're keeping a file open and receive a `SIGTERM` signal - would that initiate the `defer` functions automatically to gracefully shut down, or should one listen for `SIGTERM` signals manually, in order to invoke the defer statements?

Comment: And to answer my own question: when receiving `SIGTERM`, or call `os.Exit`, no defer calls get executed. You'll have to manually call the functions you've deferred in order to get them executed. It would then, indeed, make no sense to defer calls when you're never returning.