# "too many open files" with os.Create

Tags: go

I have around 220'000 image files (.png) to create. I run into this error message when trying to create the 1'081th file:
panic: open `/media/Snaps/pics/image1081_0.png: too many open files`

I've added the defer w.Close() line but it did not change the error.

```
    i := 1
    for i <= 223129 {

    (some other code to prepare the data and create the chart)

    img := vgimg.New(450, 600)
    dc := draw.New(img)

    canvases := table.Align(plots, dc)
    plots[0][0].Draw(canvases[0][0])
    plots[1][0].Draw(canvases[1][0])
    plots[2][0].Draw(canvases[2][0])


    testFile := "/media/Snaps/pics/image"+strconv.Itoa(i+60)+"_"+gain_loss+".png"

        w, err := os.Create(testFile)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer w.Close()

        png := vgimg.PngCanvas{Canvas: img}
        if _, err := png.WriteTo(w); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }   

        //move to next image
        i = i + 1
     }
```

Surely this limit can be worked around ? Maybe I'm not closing the files properly ?

Comment: you use `defer`, if you are in loop it won t work. The code provided is insufficient to check for it.

Comment: I've added the beginning of the loop. Should I move defer outside the loop ?

Comment: `defer` executes when the function returns, and you're going to run out of FDs before the function returns. You can't defer outside the loop (how would you?), you need to close the files in the loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720097/golang-defer-behavior

Comment: you could move the body loop into a function, within that function you can make use of defer as presented in the original code. if you use inline function take care to variable shadowing (http://oyvindsk.com/writing/common-golang-mistakes-1)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

ok, i got it, changed `defer w.Close()` to `w.Close()` and moved it after

```
png := vgimg.PngCanvas{Canvas: img}
if _, err := png.WriteTo(w); err != nil {
      panic(err)
}
```

I'm now above 10'000 images and running...

Comment: If there are any errors before you .Close() the file, Close will not be called. That is why you typocally use defer to close things. In your case I would simple add a call to an anonymous func inside the loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Defer statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)
>
> A "defer" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred to
>   the moment the surrounding function returns, either because the
>   surrounding function executed a return statement, reached the end of
>   its function body, or because the corresponding goroutine is
>   panicking.
>
> ```
> DeferStmt = "defer" Expression .
> ```
>
> The expression must be a function or method call; it cannot be
>   parenthesized. Calls of built-in functions are restricted as for
>   expression statements.
>
> Each time a "defer" statement executes, the function value and
>   parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the
>   actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred functions are
>   invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the
>   reverse order they were deferred. If a deferred function value
>   evaluates to nil, execution panics when the function is invoked, not
>   when the "defer" statement is executed.

---

In other words, if you are processing files in a loop, put the processing for a single file in a separate function to pair the `Open` with the `defer Close()`. This avoids the "too many open files" error.

For example, use a file processing structure like this to guarantee each file is closed immediately after use.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

// process single file
func processFile(name string) error {
    f, err := os.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println(fi.Name(), fi.Size())
    return nil
}

func main() {
    wd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fis, err := ioutil.ReadDir(wd)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    // process all files
    for _, fi := range fis {
        processFile(fi.Name())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/FrBWqlMOzaS

Output:

```
dev 1644
etc 1644
tmp 548
usr 822
```

Answer (score 1):

Deferred statements are not executed until the surrounding function returns, that is why your files stay open until after the for-loop.

To fix this you can simply insert an anonymous function call inside the loop:

```
for ... {
    func() {
        w, err := os.Create(testFile)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer w.Close()
        ...
    }()
}
```

That way, after each iteration of the loop, the current file is closed.