# What is the possible use case for defer?

Tags: go

What is the actual use of the `defer` keyword?

for example, instead of writing this:

```
func main() {
    f := createFile("/tmp/defer.txt")
    defer closeFile(f)
    writeFile(f)
}
```

I can just write this:

```
func main() {
    f := createFile("/tmp/defer.txt")
    writeFile(f)
    closeFile(f)
}
```

So, why should I use it instead of a usual placing of functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang defer behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720097/golang-defer-behavior)

Comment: In your simple example there is little reason (except good practices). However, in more complicated/larger functions you use defer() to ensure that certain actions are taken regardless how the functions ends -- primarily uncaught errors. For example, when I allocate a database handle I always immediately do a defer() to close the handle.

Comment: Add error handling to that code and it should be obvious.

Comment: It can't be stated enough: You need to get into the habit of handling possible errors on **everything**. Once you actually begin doing so, `defer` becomes the very obvious way of doing cleanup when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Deferred functions always get executed, even after a panic or return statement.

In real world code a lot of stuff happens between Open/Close type of call pairs, and defer lets you keep them close together in the source, and you don't have to repeat the Close call for every return statement.

Go and write some real code. The usefulness of defer will be blatantly obvious before long.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful when catching code that has the potential to panic.

Often when using `interface{}` (an "any" type) or reflection, you will encounter issues where you are trying to cast to a type that doesn't match the actual type of the data.

`defer`ing a function at the top to handle that error is how you save the day and keep your application running.