# Golang - Error while gzipping mongodb find query's cursor data, writing to a file and decompressing it

Tags: mongodb, go, amazon-s3, compression, gzip

I am iterating a mongodb cursor and gzipping the data and sending to S3 object. While trying to uncompress the uploaded file using `gzip -d`, getting the following error,

```
gzip: 9.log.gz: invalid compressed data--crc error
gzip: 9.log.gz: invalid compressed data--length error
```

The code which I'm using for iteration, compression, upload is given below,

```
// CursorReader struct acts as reader wrapper on top of mongodb cursor
type CursorReader struct {
    Csr *mongo.Cursor
}

// Read func reads the data from cursor and puts it into byte array
func (cr *CursorReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    dataAvail := cr.Csr.Next(context.TODO())
    if !dataAvail {
        n = 0
        err = io.EOF
        if cr.Csr.Close(context.TODO()) != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error: MongoDB: getting logs: close cursor: %s", err)
        }
        return
    }
    var b bytes.Buffer
    w := gzip.NewWriter(&b)
    w.Write([]byte(cr.Csr.Current.String() + "\n"))
    w.Close()
    n = copy(p, []byte(b.String()))
    err = nil
    return
}
cursor, err := coll.Find(ctx, filter) // runs the find query and returns cursor
csrRdr := new(CursorReader) // creates a new cursorreader instance
csrRdr.Csr = cursor // assigning the find cursor to cursorreader instance
_, err = s3Uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{  // Uploading the data to s3 in parts
    Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
    Key:    aws.String("key")),
    Body:   csrRdr, 
})
```

If the data is low, then I'm not getting the issue. but if the data is huge, then I'm getting error. Things I've debugged so far, trying to compress 1500 documents, each of size 15MB, getting error. Even I've tried writing the gzipped bytes directly to a file locally, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I'd remove the `+ "\n"` at the end of the writing if I were you.

Comment: @AposSpanos all the lines will get appended in a  single line, if "\n" is removed. Its not efficient for reprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the repeated call to `gzip.NewWriter()` in `func(*CursorReader) Read([]byte) (int, error)`

You are allocating a new `gzip.Writer` for each call to `Read`. `gzip` compression is stateful and so you must only use a single `Writer` instance for all the operations.

---

### Solution #1

A fairly straightforward solution to your issue would be to read all the rows in the cursor and pass it through `gzip.Writer` and storing the gzipped content into an in-memory buffer.

```golang
var cursor, _ = collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
defer cursor.Close(context.TODO())

// prepare a buffer to hold gzipped data
var buffer bytes.Buffer
var gz = gzip.NewWriter(&buffer)
defer gz.Close()

for cursor.Next(context.TODO()) {
    if _, err = io.WriteString(gz, cursor.Current.String()); err != nil {
        // handle error somehow  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    }
}

// you can now use buffer as io.Reader
// and it'll contain gzipped data for your serialized rows
_, err = s3.Upload(&s3.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("..."),
    Key:    aws.String("...")),
    Body:   &buffer, 
})
```

---

### Solution #2

Another solution would be to use [`io.Pipe()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io?tab=doc#Pipe) and [goroutines](https://golangbot.com/goroutines/) to create a stream that reads and compresses data on demand rather than in an in-memory buffer. This is useful if the data you are reading is quite large and you can't hold all of it in memory.

```golang
var cursor, _ = collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
defer cursor.Close(context.TODO())

// create pipe endpoints
reader, writer := io.Pipe()

// note: io.Pipe() returns a synchronous in-memory pipe
// reads and writes block on one another
// make sure to go through docs once.

// now, since reads and writes on a pipe blocks
// we must move to a background goroutine else
// all our writes would block forever
go func() {
    // order of defer here is important
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720120/6611700
    // make sure gzip stream is closed before the pipe
    // to ensure data is flushed properly
    defer writer.Close()
    var gz = gzip.NewWriter(writer)
    defer gz.Close()

    for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        if _, err = io.WriteString(gz, cursor.Current.String()); err != nil {
            // handle error somehow  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        }
    }
}()

// you can now use reader as io.Reader
// and it'll contain gzipped data for your serialized rows
_, err = s3.Upload(&s3.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("..."),
    Key:    aws.String("...")),
    Body:   reader, 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First one won't work for me, need to keep memory usage minimal.